# Google-Analytics: How do I add an e-mail link as the final step of a goal?

Tags: google-analytics, confirmation, confirmation-email, goal-tracking

I send a confirmation link via e-mail (in multiple places) but it seems Analytics doesn't recognize those clicks (given URL is visited) unless the visit immediate. I am guessing the last part is about session expiration.

How can I define my goal funnel so that confirmation page landings are recognized even after a day or two?

My confirmation URL is in following format:

```
"http://<domain_name>/confirmation/<10_char_hex_confirmation_code>/"
```

Answer (score 2):

You can't. All the steps of a goal funnel must occur in the same session.

You could always have one goal for signing up (i.e. sending the e-mail), and another goal for the confirmation landing page. Then compare these goal conversions, and you'll get the same story.